# 413 request entity too large + The web server connection was closed | Error 64

Tags: django, apache, nginx, django-cms

I'm currently hosting a django project on Apache + nginx. When I try to upload a large file I get a **413 request entity too large error message.**

[image: 413 request entity too large]

I also have a django-cms project and when I tried to upload a file which is anything over 5meg I get an error **code 64, The web server connection was closed.**

[image: code 64 the web server connection was closed]

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You're using both Apache and nginx?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Your error message tells it comes from nginx configuration.

You need to increase `client_max_body_size` on your `nginx.conf` server config. eg :

```
http {
    server {
        client_max_body_size 20M;
        listen       80;
        server_name  test.com;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't add it to the nginx.conf. I added it to the proxy.conf as we're running a reverse proxy server. Worked great.

Comment: I found a complement for this solution on http://cnedelcu.blogspot.com.br/2013/09/nginx-error-413-request-entity-too-large.html